# How can I draw the heliocentric and geocentric frame in one single figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I was wondering what if I mixed the geo and heliocentric frames in one figure, I got this picture, and I want now to draw it using TikZ, I don't know how to draw the 3D figures, is there any package reserved to it ?

Here's the figure I want to be drawn, I'm sorry I didn't wrote any code simply because of my extremely low level on TikZ especially on 3d figures :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you want something less fancy, but human writeable/readable:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(0,1cm)},% z-axis is straight up
x={(-3.85mm,-3.85mm)},% x-axis points down to the left
y={(1cm,0)},% y-axis points straight to the right
thick,scale=2]
% axes 
\begin{scope}[->,ultra thick]
\draw(0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)node[below left]{*} node[below=10pt]{Star 3};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0)node[right]{*} node[right=10pt]{Star 2};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2)node[above]{*} node[above=10pt]{ Star 1};
\end{scope}
% label
\draw (0,1,1) node[text width=1in]{heliocentric frame};
% sun 
\draw(0,0) circle (0.5cm);
\draw(0,0,0.5) node[above left]{Sun};
% elliptical earth's orbit around sun
\draw[dashed] (0,0) ellipse (1.875cm and 0.75cm);% 2D ellipse
% earth
\begin{scope}[shift={(1.6,1.6)},% trial and error on shift 
]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\draw (0,0) circle (0.25cm);
\draw (0,0,-0.35) node[below]{Earth};
\draw (0,0) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.1cm);% same ratio as earth orbit
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which makes this

[image: this image is the result of the Tikz code above. It shows two sets of 3D axes, one centered at the Sun and one centered at the Earth.]

Note that Tikz can do 3D coordinates, but as far as I know doesn't do 3D spheres and ellipses with it's built in commands.  I forgot to add the text for "Geocentric frame" but adding it would be a good way to warm up for the new Tikz user!

Comment: I approve surely :-)

Answer (score 4):

Created with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor)....for the newbie of *TiKZ*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_uheif1z99/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{89.1 bp } { -128.7 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1.32 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_14c0b43mh}{\pgfpoint{-72bp}{104bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(0.88,0.35,0.41);
rgb(3.392857142857143bp)=(0.88,0.35,0.41);
rgb(23.125bp)=(0.91,0.92,0.15);
rgb(400bp)=(0.91,0.92,0.15)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_kqmi50mn3/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformrotate{0 }  \pgftransformscale{2 }  }}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{_aibr68kxs}{150bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.72,0.88,0.99);
rgb(37.5bp)=(0.72,0.88,0.99);
rgb(40bp)=(0.66,0.82,0.95);
rgb(43.75bp)=(0.56,0.73,0.89);
rgb(46.75bp)=(0.56,0.74,0.92);
rgb(50bp)=(0.56,0.75,0.94);
rgb(50.25bp)=(0.42,0.66,0.9);
rgb(58.25bp)=(0.64,0.85,0.96);
rgb(62.5bp)=(0.74,0.95,0.99);
rgb(100bp)=(0.74,0.95,0.99)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_l7q4mzgni/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_aqts5od14}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(0.93,0.89,0.51);
rgb(0.08928571428571429bp)=(0.93,0.89,0.51);
rgb(25bp)=(0.95,0.85,0.21);
rgb(400bp)=(0.95,0.85,0.21)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_3fitct74g/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformrotate{0 }  \pgftransformscale{2 }  }}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{_g98vur5av}{150bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.95,0.77,0.74);
rgb(37.5bp)=(0.95,0.77,0.74);
rgb(50bp)=(0.91,0.42,0.34);
rgb(50.25bp)=(0.92,0.16,0.01);
rgb(56.25bp)=(1,0.4,0);
rgb(62.5bp)=(0.78,0.13,0);
rgb(100bp)=(0.78,0.13,0)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_cusdwq5fb/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformrotate{0 }  \pgftransformscale{2 }  }}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{_cf4x2w32q}{150bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.72,0.88,0.99);
rgb(37.5bp)=(0.72,0.88,0.99);
rgb(40.535714285714285bp)=(0.66,0.82,0.95);
rgb(50.25bp)=(0.56,0.36,0.17);
rgb(60.12416294642857bp)=(0.64,0.85,0.96);
rgb(62.5bp)=(0.74,0.95,0.99);
rgb(100bp)=(0.74,0.95,0.99)}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,464); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 464

%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp812091251605362] 
\draw [line width=1.5]  (294.92,319.37) -- (342,319.37)(299.63,277) -- (299.63,324.08) (335,314.37) -- (342,319.37) -- (335,324.37) (294.63,284) -- (299.63,277) -- (304.63,284)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23673456966432171] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (299.63,319.37) -- (277.12,341.88) ;
\draw [shift={(275,344)}, rotate = 315] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;

%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp05090589551403468] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (189,268.5) -- (404,268.5)(210.5,75) -- (210.5,290) (397,263.5) -- (404,268.5) -- (397,273.5) (205.5,82) -- (210.5,75) -- (215.5,82)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3138825477839955] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (210.5,268.5) -- (100.12,378.88) ;
\draw [shift={(98,381)}, rotate = 315] [color={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;

%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp6358119726686489] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (31.73,268.5) .. controls (31.73,237.23) and (111.77,211.88) .. (210.5,211.88) .. controls (309.23,211.88) and (389.27,237.23) .. (389.27,268.5) .. controls (389.27,299.77) and (309.23,325.13) .. (210.5,325.13) .. controls (111.77,325.13) and (31.73,299.77) .. (31.73,268.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6603692222286022] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_14c0b43mh,_uheif1z99] (185.5,268.5) .. controls (185.5,254.69) and (196.69,243.5) .. (210.5,243.5) .. controls (224.31,243.5) and (235.5,254.69) .. (235.5,268.5) .. controls (235.5,282.31) and (224.31,293.5) .. (210.5,293.5) .. controls (196.69,293.5) and (185.5,282.31) .. (185.5,268.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Star [id:dp3210625600697121] 
\path  [shading=_aibr68kxs,_kqmi50mn3] (423,249) -- (426.53,263.15) -- (441.07,262.13) -- (428.71,269.85) -- (434.17,283.37) -- (423,274) -- (411.83,283.37) -- (417.29,269.85) -- (404.93,262.13) -- (419.47,263.15) -- cycle ; % for fading 
 \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (423,249) -- (426.53,263.15) -- (441.07,262.13) -- (428.71,269.85) -- (434.17,283.37) -- (423,274) -- (411.83,283.37) -- (417.29,269.85) -- (404.93,262.13) -- (419.47,263.15) -- cycle ; % for border 

%Shape: Star [id:dp30385001322189864] 
\path  [shading=_aqts5od14,_l7q4mzgni] (91.47,369.85) -- (95,384) -- (109.54,382.98) -- (97.18,390.71) -- (102.64,404.23) -- (91.47,394.85) -- (80.31,404.23) -- (85.77,390.71) -- (73.4,382.98) -- (87.95,384) -- cycle ; % for fading 
 \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (91.47,369.85) -- (95,384) -- (109.54,382.98) -- (97.18,390.71) -- (102.64,404.23) -- (91.47,394.85) -- (80.31,404.23) -- (85.77,390.71) -- (73.4,382.98) -- (87.95,384) -- cycle ; % for border 

%Shape: Star [id:dp7745183315132196] 
\path  [shading=_g98vur5av,_3fitct74g] (210,43) -- (214.11,56.34) -- (228.07,56.13) -- (216.66,64.16) -- (221.17,77.37) -- (210,69) -- (198.83,77.37) -- (203.34,64.16) -- (191.93,56.13) -- (205.89,56.34) -- cycle ; % for fading 
 \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (210,43) -- (214.11,56.34) -- (228.07,56.13) -- (216.66,64.16) -- (221.17,77.37) -- (210,69) -- (198.83,77.37) -- (203.34,64.16) -- (191.93,56.13) -- (205.89,56.34) -- cycle ; % for border 

%Shape: Circle [id:dp4466353465802877] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_cf4x2w32q,_cusdwq5fb] (289,317.25) .. controls (289,311.31) and (293.81,306.5) .. (299.75,306.5) .. controls (305.69,306.5) and (310.5,311.31) .. (310.5,317.25) .. controls (310.5,323.19) and (305.69,328) .. (299.75,328) .. controls (293.81,328) and (289,323.19) .. (289,317.25) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (156,236) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {\textit{Sun}};
% Text Node
\draw (301.75,331) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Geocentric\\frame};
% Text Node
\draw (245,291) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {\textit{Earth}};
% Text Node
\draw (400,230) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Star 2};
% Text Node
\draw (187,22) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Star 1};
% Text Node
\draw (60,405) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Star 3};
% Text Node
\draw (251.75,152) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large] [align=left] {Heliocentric frame};


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]